# Schema object properties validation

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

According to OpenAPI specification [https://swagger.io/specification/] I can define the minimum and maximum values of the field in the schema object properties.

But actually Google endpoint does not perform any validation

My Swagger file fragment:
parameters:

```
    - name: message 

      in: body 

      description: sug

      schema:

        required:

          - Message

        properties:

          Message:

            type: integer

            minimum: 1

            maximum: 1

          MessageId:
```

When I send a wrong request:
curl https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd"Message=10&MessageId=456789123456&TimeStamp=20190611101010212&OperatorId=15&GlobalAccountId=81165751216851320000&Reason=3" 
The Endpoint does not reject the request, but invokes the cloud function.

Comment: Taking a look at the link you've provided and also [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#models-with-composition) I see that the keyword used is `schemas` instead of `schema`, that could be what is causing the error. In the aforementioned link, there's an example pretty similar to the one you are using, can you check if the issue was related to that difference in the keyword?

Comment: Thanks, bhito.The syntax is correct. This is copy/paste from Google developer portal. The problem is that the endpoint does not perform required validation.

Comment: Have you tried using the minimum and maximum validator separately? You could try enabling minimum first and try to make it work and do the same with maximum. The issue maybe is due to the parameters being treated as a logical `OR` instead of a logical `AND`. If that's the case, 10 would comply with the `minimum: 1` restriction and therefore the message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Google Cloud Endpoints doesn't do any OpenAPI object property validation.